# garbled text in image upon enlarging it

Tags: inkscape, text

See image on Wikimedia Commons. If you view the image on a higher resolution (2000px), the text becomes a mess. What can be done about it? 
(Note that some of the text is grouped in root. Ungrouping the text doesn't have any effect.)

[map of Estonia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Estonia_-_Location_Map_(2013)_-_EST_-_UNOCHA.svg)

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture highlighting your problem and answer the following questions: 1) Did you create that file? 2) Is the text rendered correctly on your machine? 3) Is the specified font available on your machine? 4) What font is specified in the SVG?

Comment: Hi, could you upload some screenshots and clarify which image you mean and what you mean by 'a mess'? There are various sized PNGs and an SVG all linked on that page - All of which look fine to me.

Comment: Ad 1: I didn't create the file. I edited it (I removed the watermark in the image). Ad 2: When I open the file with Inkscape all looks fine but that is deceiving. Opening it with rsvg-view one can see that after enlarging the picture the text becomes garbled. Ad 4: The font used in the image is Sans and Liberation Sans. Ad 3: yes, the font is available on my machine.

Comment: If you press the 2000 png link on the page I have given, you will see that the text is not depicted in the right way. For instance, watch the word "Russian Federation" change. This only occurs on the 2000px size. This happens in all the images in the same category. Unfortunately, I have given this image where it happens less than in the other ones.

Comment: I added the image. See the text "Russian Federation". Like I said, this happens in the other pictures in the same category much more. At 2000px png, the text begins to move.

Comment: @user3467407 this is a bug in your rendering engine. I have no problem in zooming this much in in illustrator. PS: your showing south America trough the globe

Comment: It is well-known that the rendering engine of Illustrator is more forgiving than other editors. The engine of Wikimedia Commons, Inkscape and SVG-viewer rsvg-view all produce the same image with the same problem: garbled text upon enlarging.

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known that the rendering engine of Illustrator is more forgiving than other editors. The engine of Wikimedia Commons, Inkscape and the SVG-viewer rsvg-view all produce the same image with the same problem: garbled text upon enlarging. I have inspected the properties of the text more closely. The text is probably copied and pasted into the text because it lacks properties. When one takes a look into the stroke paint it says: "Stroke paint: Unset paint (make it undefined so it can be inherited)". So there is no stroke paint. I edited that to Flat Color and the problem was gone. But all the text in the picture needs to be changed. Thank you for your answers, all of you.